# How to rewrite the result of the terminal in a txt

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, url-rewriting

I'm using a python library called nlpnet.
This library is a tagger of words from the Brazilian Portuguese language, after many tempting, to achieve the result in the terminal:
[Output of tagged data in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga9IU.jpg)

What we can perceive in the image of the terminal and that it classifies each word individually with the abbreviation of its grammatical class. The challenge is for the algorithm to scour the entire analyzed document and rewrite only sentences containing more than 5 words of certain grammar classes of my choice.

Example: Analyze a txt document with several sentences, and rewrite in another file only sentences that have more than 5 verbs or adjectives.

Code used:
Class to prepare the labeler:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import nlpnet


def get_tags(content):
    #Labeling templates directory
    data_dir = 'pos-pt';
    #Definition of the directory and language to be used
    tagger = nlpnet.POSTagger(data_dir, language='pt');

    for i in range(content.__len__()):
        str = content[i];
        # Método para a etiquetação da sentença
        tagged_str = tagger.tag(str);
        print(tagged_str);

    return content;
```

Class of file:`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import codecs
import teste


def loadContent():
    # Loading data set
    positiveData = codecs.open('opiniaoaborto.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').readlines()

    data_set = [0 for i in range(2000)]
    label_set = [0 for i in range(2000)]

    data_set[:1000] = positiveData

    for i in range(2000):
        if i < 1000:
            label_set[i] = "p"
        else:
            label_set[i] = "n"

        # returning X feature set, y
    return data_set, label_set


content, label = loadContent()

content = teste.get_tags(content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to POS tag the sentences of a document, and dump to a file the sentences that contain more than N occurrences of a particular POS of your choice, you won't need the 2nd script you posted.

This is an extremely simplified example:

```
import os
import nlpnet

TAGGER = nlpnet.POSTagger('pos-pt', language='pt')


# You could have a function that tagged and verified if a
# sentence meets the criteria for storage.

def is_worth_saving(text, pos, pos_count):
    # tagged sentences are lists of tagged words, which in
    # nlpnet are (word, pos) tuples. Tagged texts may contain
    # several sentences.
    pos_words = [word for sentence in TAGGER.tag(text)
                 for word in sentence
                 if word[1] == pos]
    return len(pos_words) >= pos_count


# Then you'd just need to open your original file, read a sentence, tag
# it, decide if it's worth saving, and save it or not. Until you consume 
# the entire original file. Thus not loading the entire dataset in memory 
# and keeping a small memory footprint.

with open('opiniaoaborto.txt', encoding='utf8') as original_file:
    with open('oracaos_interessantes.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for text in original_file:
            # For example, only save sentences with more than 5 verbs in it
            if is_worth_saving(text, 'V', 5):
                output_file.write(text + os.linesep)
```

To answer your follow-up. You want to check whether a sentence contains 5 words that are tagged with any of the POS in a given list. I picture two scenarios:

A) The 5 words must belong to the same POS. For example, sentences with 5 verbs ('Comendo, dançando, procurando, olhando e falando') or 5 nouns ('O gato, o sapo, o cão, o loro e o ratão foram as compras') but not 5 verbs+nouns ('O gato esta querendo comer o ratão' [2 nouns, 3 verbs]).

```
import os
import nlpnet
from collections import Counter

TAGGER = nlpnet.POSTagger('pos-pt', language='pt')    

# the POS arguments would need to be a list now
def is_worth_saving(text, pos_list, pos_count):
    interesting_words = Counter()
    for sentence in TAGGER.tag(text):
        for word, pos in sentence:
            if pos in pos_list:
                interesting_words[pos] += 1

    return any(particular_pos_count >= pos_count
               for _, particular_pos_count
               in interesting_words.items())

# Since the argument which receives our desired POS categories takes
# lists of POS categories now, we also have to change the way we
# invoke `is_worth_saving`

with open('opiniaoaborto.txt', encoding='utf8') as original_file:
    with open('oracaos_interessantes.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for text in original_file:
            # For example, only save sentences with more than 5 verbs or nouns in it
            if is_worth_saving(text, ['V', 'N'], 5):  # Notice the POS argument takes lists now
                output_file.write(text + os.linesep)
```

B) Sentence contains 5 POS composed of the sum of any of the POS in a list. For example: 'O gato esta querendo comer o ratão' (2 nouns + 3 verbs)

```
import os
import nlpnet

TAGGER = nlpnet.POSTagger('pos-pt', language='pt')

# Again, one of the arguments would have to take a list of valid POS
def is_worth_saving(text, pos_list, pos_count):
    pos_words = [word for sentence in TAGGER.tag(text)
                 for word in sentence
                 if word[1] in pos_list]
    return len(pos_words) >= pos_count

with open('opiniaoaborto.txt', encoding='utf8') as original_file:
    with open('oracaos_interessantes.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for text in original_file:
            # For example, only save sentences whose sum of verbs and nouns count is 5
            if is_worth_saving(text, ['V', 'N'], 5):
                output_file.write(text + os.linesep)
```

Comment: Compiled the file and presented the following error::
"TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"
I tried to open the file in another way, but giving error persists.

Comment: You're using python2 most likely. Just switch the calls to `open` for calls to `codecs.open`.  Or even better, get Python 3

Comment: Already tried to change the selection parameter and nothing. I've tested if you have any issues and you have given everything correct. Only this error is a barrier.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Classificador de palavras/Classificador.py", line 22, in <module>
    if is_worth_saving(sentence, 'V', 5):
  File "D:/Classificador de palavras/Classificador.py", line 14, in is_worth_saving
    if word[5] == pos]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: The problematic line is `if word[1] == pos`, which you seem to have changed to `if word[5] == pos`. The reason for the `word[1]` is that nplnet tagger produces tuples of `(word, tag)` for each word in the sentence, so `word[1]` is accessing the tag of each word and comparing it to `pos`. I don't understand why you changed it to `word[5]`. The error is literally saying: word doesn't have an element 5, it only has 2 elements (word, tag)

Comment: Algorithm presents same error using parameter word[1]

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Classificador de palavras/Classificador.py", line 23, in <module>
    if is_worth_saving(sentence, 'V', 5):
  File "D:/Classificador de palavras/Classificador.py", line 15, in is_worth_saving
    if word[1] == pos]
IndexError: list index out of range
`

Comment: I looked through nlpnet's source, the result of the tagger consists of nested collections of text > sentence > word. Something like `[[(word1, pos1), (word2, pos2)], [(word3, pos1), (word4, pos2)]]` for a two-sentences text.  That's where the issue was coming from, and I have edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: I stayed with another doubt, I based on your example try to get only sentences that presented 5 words from any of the following grammatical classes: noun, verb, adverb and adjective.

I thought of the following code to complement your example,  I made this pseudo code:
`tagger = nlpnet.POSTagger(data_dir, language = 'pt');`
`tagged_str = tagger.tag(str);`
` #print(tagged_str);`
`return str, tagged_str[0];`
`tupla[0] => primeiro elemento, tupla[1] => segundo elemento`
`if(tupla[1] == 'N' or ....) `

In this pseudo code I tried to work with string, would I have another way?

Comment: I try to apply a new function, but without success
`def isOpenWord(tag): if( tag == 'N' or tag == 'ADJ' or tag == 'ADV'): return True;    else:   return False`

Comment: @Rivaldo I just extended my answer to cover your follow-ups

Comment: If I want to capture words individually, which parameter should I modify?

Answer (score 0):

When running the program in command line, write `$python python_filename.py > savingfilename.txt`. This will save everything that prints on the screen to a text file.